# Why does bind seem to present arguments as arrays?

Tags: javascript

It was my impression that I could pass arguments to a function by using `bind` and then call on those arguments as if they had been passed normally. Why do I need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var func = function(button) {
    button[0].on('click', function() {
      alert('Hello World.');
    })
  }
  func.bind(null, [$('.button')])();
});
```

When it seems like I should be able to just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var func = function(button) {
    button.on('click', function() {
      alert('Hello World.');
    })
  }
  func.bind(null, [$('.button')])();
});
```

Example, treating the `button` argument as an array:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var func = function(button) {
    button[0].on('click', function() {
      alert('Hello World.');
    })
  }
  func.bind(null, [$('.button')])();
});
```

```css
html, body, div {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.button {
  background-color:gray;
  margin:50px;
  padding:50px;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: It's treating it as an array because you're binding an array.

Answer (score 3):

[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is used to bind the current calling scope to a function so that even if you call it from somewhere else, it will know about local variables in that bound scope.

What you're looking for is [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply).

```js
var func = function(button) {
  button.on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello world');
  });
}

func.apply(this, [$('.button')]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```

For completeness, there's also a [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) function that is more commonly used. Instead of an array of arguments, it uses a list of arguments after the initial scope argument.

```
func.call(this, $('.button'));
```

Comment: `.apply()` is better, but even that doesn't make too much sense here when `.call()` could be used instead. Don't forget to remove the trailing `()`

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the trailing `()`. I originally suggested `call()` as well but it seemed like the OP wanted to be able to pass an array of args, so `apply()` is the most correct approach.

Comment: I see, yeah if the OP already has an array then `.apply()` is the solution.

Comment: I added a remark about `call()` for completeness to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) wrong. You shouldn't give it an array of arguments, you should just give the arguments themselves:

```js
function print(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x, y, z);      
}

print12 = print.bind(null, 1, 2);

print12(3); // 1, 2, 3
```

Also, as Soviut mentioned, if you're calling `.bind(...)()`, you probably want [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) or [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) instead.

Comment: Oh, what if I have a dynamic number of arguments I want to pass to the function? Edit: I see, the answer above shows the one I need to use is `apply`

Comment: @curiosity5678 Use something like [`.apply(null, [arg1, arg2, arg3, ...])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @curiosity5678 If you want to call `bind` with a dynamic number of arguments you use `Function.bind.apply(myFunction, [thisValue, arg1, arg2 /* ... */])`

Comment: Or ES6 `var bound = myFunction.bind(thisArg, ...myArrayOfArgs)`